# Put all IEs older than IE9 into quirks mode via HTML directives

Tags: html, internet-explorer, doctype, quirks-mode

I want my page to be rendered in Quirks mode in IE6, IE7 and IE8. I want to keep all other browsers (recent versions) in HTML5 standards mode.

What does not work:

- Put the DOCTYPE declaration into second line (known measure in IE, but will trigger quirks in IE9 as well)
- Omit the DOCTYPE declaration (will trigger quirks in at least FF, [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Web_Developer_FAQ))

Any ideas, how I could accomplish this via purely HTML measures?

Some background:

Because of heavy usage of the border box model, my page layout happens to render best if the older IEs are in Quirks mode.
Support for `box-sizing` did not appear in IE before version 8.
There is sum other stuff, that also works better in IE8 quirks.

My use of the border box model:

```
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: Worst idea *ever*. Surely Quirks Mode will cause other problems with your page?

Comment: As a note, IE8 supports box-sizing too. You can use no DOCTYPE (or insert a comment before a DOCTYPE) but add an X-UA-Compatible with IE=edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can establish this using the X-UA-Compatible meta tag in combination with conditional comments.

First, use a conditional comment to hide the  tag from IE 9 and later:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
```

Then, insert a meta tag that triggers quirks mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5.5" />
```

Next, close your conditional comment:

```
<![endif]-->
```

Also, make sure you start your document with a `<!doctype html>` so IE9 won't be in Quirks mode; if it already uses the IE 5.5 rendering engine it won't ignore the conditional comment.

- [More about conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [About the X-UA-Compatible header / `<meta>` tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SetMode)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly what you asked for, but have you considered [using **ie7-js**](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)?

> IE7.js is a JavaScript library to make
>   Microsoft Internet Explorer behave
>   like a standards-compliant browser. It
>   fixes many HTML and CSS issues.

[Here's the test case for `box-sizing: border-box`.](http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/box-sizing.html)

If anything else on your page uses JavaScript, I believe this is the best solution.

Comment: Actually, I already have PIE (for rounded corners) and modernizr, etc. on page. But IE9.js throws an error in IE7 (and fails) and does not correctly render my page in IE8. I had removed the other scripts for the test. Nice idea though, thanks!

Comment: The closest I could get to answering your actual question was keeping the doctype and adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5" />` - that will get you Standards Mode in all browsers but IE, where you'll get Quirks Mode. The problem is that IE9 *also* gets Quirks Mode. And I can't think of a way to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9, ie=5">
```